# Including a flutter aar into a flutter project (to obfuscate code)

Tags: android, flutter

I have dart library that I'm already distributing to clients as aar and xcframework binaries. Now I would like to distribute it to clients who would integrate it in their flutter app. To keep the code obfuscated (I did some research and could not find a way to use a flutter library without having access to the source code). I'm making a flutter poc where i will integrate the aar and the ios frameworks into the native side of the flutter app and use methodChannels to communicate with my module. I started with the android integration. But cannot make that work.
In the MainActivity in the android folder of my host app I try to initalize an engine with an entry point in my module.

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println("poc Hello from Android 0")
        val dartEntrypoint =
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint(
                FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader().findAppBundlePath(), "german"
            )
        val sdkEngine : FlutterEngine = FlutterEngine(applicationContext)
        sdkEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(dartEntrypoint)
        println("poc Hello from Android 1 ${sdkEngine}")
        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put("sdkEngine", sdkEngine)
        MethodChannel(sdkEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,           "com.example/scan").invokeMethod("scan", null, object : MethodChannel.Result {
            override fun success(result: Any?) {
                // Handle success returned from Flutter
                println("poc SCAN called from Android")
            }

            override fun error(code: String, message: String?, details: Any?) {
                // Handle error returned from Flutter
                println("poc Received error: $code $message")
            }

            override fun notImplemented() {
                // Handle method not implemented on Flutter side
                println("poc Method not implemented on Flutter side")
                throw NotImplementedError()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

i get this error when ecuting the entry point

```
E/flutter (11552): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(667)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
E/flutter (11552): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(168)] Could not run the run main Dart entrypoint.
E/flutter (11552): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(436)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (11552): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(637)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

my module has the entry point

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> german() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: kIsWeb
        ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
        : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
  );
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;

    if (iosInfo.utsname.machine.contains('iPhone')) {
      startMethodChannels();
    } else {
      throw Exception("Unsupported Platform, the SDK supports iPhones only");
    }
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    startMethodChannels();
  } else {
    throw Exception("Unsupported Platform, the SDK supports iOS And Android");
  }
}
```

i imported the aar in the app/build.gradle as instructed by the flutter build aar command

```
String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"
repositories {
    maven {
        url '/Users/username/zdev/ios-sdk-bridge/build/host/outputs/repo'
    }
    maven {
        url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation 'com.trackbar.tracker_sdk_bridge:flutter_debug:1.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.trackbar.tracker_sdk_bridge:flutter_release:1.0'
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Probably lot's more people will have as Dart / Flutter is a convenient way to write multiplatform code, but we don't want to share our source code with 3rd parties

Comment: I tried fro but but to no avail. I've put this issue on the side for now but i plan to look into it more later. I was thinking of maybe implementing an obfuscater.